# Call Python function with overloaded PySide signal without passing arguments

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to call the same function within a PySide application from a threaded worker in different ways. Overloading the PySide Signal with `test_sig = Signal((), (int,), (str,))`, providing three slots (`@Slot()`, `@Slot(int)` and `@Slot(str)`) to a test function, and then emitting each signal (`test_sig.emit()`, `test_sig[int].emit(1)` and `test_sig[str].emit('a')`) works for the integer and string cases. But, no matter what I try I can't get the test function to be called with no argument passed.

From what I've tried it seems when a Signal is overloaded, emitting the `test_sig.emit()` isn't emitted immediately. Only if the first of the next defined overloaded Signals (`[str]` in my case) is emitted, it is emitted **twice**.

I'm using Python 3.9 and PySide==1.15.1. Here is my minimal working example:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QRunnable, QObject, QThreadPool, Slot, Signal
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


# Signals class
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    test_sig = Signal((), (str,), (int,))
    finished = Signal()


# Test worker
class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self.signals.test_sig.emit()  # Trying to call function with no args
        self.signals.test_sig[int].emit(1)  # Call function with int
        self.signals.test_sig[str].emit('a')  # Call function with str
        self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.run_test()

    def run_test(self):
        worker = Worker()
        worker.signals.test_sig.connect(self.test_func)  # I suspect this might be what I'm doing wrong
        worker.signals.test_sig[int].connect(self.test_func)
        worker.signals.test_sig[str].connect(self.test_func)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.test_finished)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    @Slot()
    @Slot(int)
    @Slot(str)
    def test_func(self, arg=None):
        test_result = 'Test reached'
        if arg:
            test_result += f', arg received and is a {type(arg)}.'
        else:
            test_result += ' and no arg received.'
        print(test_result)

    @Slot()
    def test_finished(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The terminal output of which is:

```
Test reached, arg received and is a <class 'int'>.
Test reached, arg received and is a <class 'str'>.
Test reached, arg received and is a <class 'str'>.
```

The only workaround I've found is to overload the Signal with `test_sig = Signal((int,), (str,))`, emit with `test_sig.emit(None)` and not to connect the `test_sig.connect()` Signal, which results in the following terminal output:

```
Test reached and no arg received.
Test reached, arg received and is a <class 'int'>.
Test reached, arg received and is a <class 'str'>.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is clearly a bug. So that `Signal` does not allow to establish an overload signal without an argument, besides that it does not eliminate the buffer of the previous information.

In [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5), on the other hand, the expected behavior is observed, so that allows us to point out that it is not a [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) bug but only [pyside2](/questions/tagged/pyside2).

I have created [`PYSIDE-1427`](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1427) bug.